# Solving the recurrence $S_{n+1} = S_n^2-2$

Tags: reference-request, recurrence-relations

**Note.** This question is not solely about solving the recurrence below, I already know the solution. I would like to get a reference, preferably a textbook, which summarizes methods to explicitly solve recurrence relations such that the methods of that textbook are sufficient to solve \eqref{*} below.

The recurrence \begin{equation}\tag{*}\label{*}S_{n+1} = S_n^2-2\end{equation} is the basis for the Lukas-Lehmer primality test and it is a classical result from the literature that for $S_0 = 4$, the solution to \eqref{*} is given by \begin{equation}\label{Sol}\tag{Sol}S_n = (2+\sqrt 3)^{2^n}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{2^n}.\end{equation}

It is easy to  verify that the $S_n$ given in \eqref{Sol} indeed satisfy \eqref{*}. However, I would like to have some reference, *preferably a book with comprehensive overview of explicit solutions to recurrence relations*, which explains the idea behind \eqref{Sol}.

---

*My thoughts:* I will follow the ideas of [1; Chapter 1.4]. It is left as an exercise to verify that for all $z\in\mathbb C$, $$\cos(2z) = Q(\cos(z)),$$

where $$Q\in\mathbb R[z], \\ Q(z)=2z^2-1$$ is the *second Tschebyscheff polynomial.* Our goal is to know more about the iterates of the map \begin{align}f:\mathbb C&\to\mathbb C, \\z&\mapsto z^2-2.\end{align}

We have $f = \phi\circ Q\circ\phi^{-1}$, where $\phi:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is given by $\phi(z)=2z$. So $f^{\circ n} = \phi\circ Q^{\circ n}\circ\phi^{-1}$. But we can compute, thanks to the cosine identity above, $$Q^{\circ n}(\cos(z)) = \cos(2^n z)$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $z\in\mathbb C$.

Thus, let $y\in\mathbb C$ and let $z\in\mathbb C$ be any solution to $y=\cos(z)$ (with an  abuse of notation I will write $z=\arccos(y)$). The solution exists by [3].

Then $$S_n = f^{\circ n}(S_0)=2Q^{\circ n}(S_0/2)=2\cos(2^n\arccos(S_0/2)).$$

This is a fairly explicit formula and as noted by podiki below, one can obtain \eqref{Sol} directly from this formula using particular values of the complex exponential.

## Literature

[1] Alan F. Beardon: *Iteration of Rational Functions*. (1991)
[2] Related question: [If $x_1=5$, $x_{n+1}=x_n^2-2$, find $\lim x_{n+1}/(x_1\cdots x_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/121608/631742).
[3] [Prove that $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ are surjective over the complex numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/839213/631742)

Comment: You want another solution than your *My thoughts* or a reference/a book that explans your solution  *My thoughts*?

Comment: Besides, for $n = 0$, you must have $S_0 = 4$, not $2$

Comment: @Nn2 Yes thank you, now fixed. And see my new note at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Well, if $ab = 1,$   then $(a+b)^2 - 2 = a^2 + b^2,$  while we still have $a^2 b^2 = 1;$  we can repeat. Any $S_0 > 2$ can be written as $a + \frac{1}{a}, $ induction says $S_n = a^{2^n} + \frac{1}{a^{2^n}}.$ Keep in mind that there is no nice expression if we take $T_{n+1}= T_n^2 -1$ for example. Don't know any references  other than complex dynamics for $z^2 + C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence $S_{n+1} = S_n^2-2$ belongs to the class of *doubly exponential sequences*.

> An instructive treatment can be found in section 2.2.3 of *[Mathematics for the Analysis of Algorithms](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/mathematics-for-the-analysis-of-algorithms)* by D. H. Greene and D. E. Knuth (with the title of this section being the name of this class).
>
> This section treats in detail the more general recurrence relation
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{x_{n+1}=x_n^2+g_n}\tag{2.72}
> \end{align*}
> where $g_n$ is a slowly growing function of $n$ possibly depending on the earlier members of the sequence.

The authors consider also two special cases of (2.72), namely

- **Golomb's nonlinear recurrence:**
  \begin{align*}
  y_{n+1}=y_0y_1\cdots y_n+r,\qquad y_0=1\tag{2.88}
  \end{align*}
  which can be shown to be equivalent to the finite-history recurrence
  \begin{align*}
  y_{n+1}=\left(y_n-r\right)y_n+r,\qquad y_0=1,y_1=r+1\tag{2.89}
  \end{align*}
  Completing the square using the substitution $x_n=y_n-\frac{r}{2}$ we obtain
  \begin{align*}
  x_{n+1}=x_n^2+\frac{r}{2}-\frac{r^2}{4}\tag{2.91}
  \end{align*}
  showing it's a special case of (2.72).
- **Balanced Trees:**

  The number of balanced binary trees of height $n$ is given by the recurrence
  \begin{align*}
  y_{n+1}=y_n^2+2y_ny_{n-1}\tag{2.92}
  \end{align*}
  Making the transformation $x_n=y_n+y_{n-1}$ we obtain
  \begin{align*}
  x_{n+1}=x_n^2+2y_{n-1}y_{n-2}\tag{2.93}
  \end{align*}
  Following the authors we find the term $g_n$ is not constant, but grows slowly enough $\left(2y_{n-1}y_{n-2}\ll y_n < x_n\right)$ to meet the requirements on $g_n$.

**Notes:**

- According to the authors the techniques used in this section 2.2.3 are presented in the paper *[Some Doubly Exponential Sequences](http://neilsloane.com/doc/doubly.html)* by A. V. Aho and N. J. A. Sloane. They finally cite in this section two recurrence relations from this paper
  \begin{align*}
  y_{n+1}&=y_n^3-3y_n\\
  y_{n+1}&=y_ny_{n-1}+1
  \end{align*}
  indicating that although they are not precisely of the form (2.72) the techniques can also be used to attack these recurrence relations.
- In the cited paper (section 2.3) we also find closely related to OPs recurrence relation:
  \begin{align*}
   x_{n+1}=x_n^2-1\qquad n\geq 0
   \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want $S_0=2$ this leads to the constant sequence $S_n=2$. Your formula has $S_0=4$.

$$\begin{align}2\cos(2^n\arccos(S_0/2))&=e^{i2^n\arccos(2)}+e^{-i2^n\arccos(2)}\\
&=(e^{i\arccos(2)})^{2^n}+(e^{-i\arccos(2)})^{2^n}\\
&=(2+\sqrt{3})^{2^n}+(2-\sqrt{3})^{2^n}\\ \end{align}$$

where I used the fact that the solutions to $\cos(z)=2$, satisfy

$$e^{iz}=2\pm\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: Yes, thank you, I meant $S_0=4$.

Comment: Also thank you for this nice bridge between the first part and second part. I am looking for a book which does everything here systematically :)

Comment: Yes, sorry this doesn't really answer your actual question, just get back to your original formula and was too long to leave in a comment.